# Yahoo OpenID returning invalid signature with passport-yahoo

Tags: node.js, openid, passport.js, yahoo-api

As of today, Dec 10th, 2013, it seems that passport-yahoo is unable to correctly complete the openid workflow. We are getting an invalid signature. My knowledge of openid is quite limited, and I am still looking into the issue. Can anyone provide some insight into this problem? Is anyone else running in to the same problem?

Here is the stack trace from node:

```
{
"message":"Failed to verify assertion",
"stack":"Failed to verify assertion (message: Invalid signature)
    at app/node_modules/passport-yahoo/node_modules/passport-openid/lib/passport-openid/strategy.js:184:36
    at app/node_modules/passport-yahoo/node_modules/passport-openid/node_modules/openid/openid.js:1063:12
    at app/node_modules/passport-yahoo/node_modules/passport-openid/node_modules/openid/openid.js:1188:14
    at app/node_modules/passport-yahoo/node_modules/passport-openid/node_modules/openid/openid.js:1269:7
    at Object.openid.loadAssociation (app/node_modules/passport-yahoo/node_modules/passport-openid/node_modules/openid/openid.js:107:5)
    at _checkSignatureUsingAssociation (app/node_modules/passport-yahoo/node_modules/passport-openid/node_modules/openid/openid.js:1231:10)
    at _checkSignature (app/node_modules/passport-yahoo/node_modules/passport-openid/node_modules/openid/openid.js:1221:5)
    at _verifyAssertionAgainstProvider (app/node_modules/passport-yahoo/node_modules/passport-openid/node_modules/openid/openid.js:1184:3)
    at app/node_modules/passport-yahoo/node_modules/passport-openid/node_modules/openid/openid.js:1155:16
    at app/node_modules/passport-yahoo/node_modules/passport-openid/node_modules/openid/openid.js:678:7
    at app/node_modules/passport-yahoo/node_modules/passport-openid/node_modules/openid/openid.js:533:11
    at done (app/node_modules/passport-yahoo/node_modules/passport-openid/node_modules/openid/openid.js:254:9)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (app/node_modules/passport-yahoo/node_modules/passport-openid/node_modules/openid/openid.js:258:32)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:920:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)",
"name":"InternalOpenIDError",
"openidError":{"message":"Invalid signature"}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - we started having intermittent issues starting this past Friday, then complete failure today. From Y! developer forums, it seems others are having the same problem - http://developer.yahoo.com/forum/OpenID-General-Discussion/OpenID-login-with-Yahoo-broke-today/1386713784256-49fd81b6-7752-4c9f-8b7c-728235c46bae

And in general testing a number of OpenID sites, Yahoo login doesn't work